# How can we get an initial piece of JavaScript to run without referencing a function in your XHTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

Can we you get our JavaScript to run in the first place to
assign an event handler?

How can we get an initial piece of JavaScript to run without referencing a function in your XHTML page?

Comment: I don't quite get it. What do you mean by *function in XHTML page*? And I also think that maybe you're thinking too complicated. What do you want to achieve eventually?

Comment: What do you mean? Sending JavaScript in the response headers so it runs before the HTML content is even evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code you put in a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag will be executed immediately. Put it in your `<head>` and it will run before anything else. Put at the end of the `<body>` and it will run last.

Do keep in mind that the DOM may not be fully initialized in either of those cases. If you need the DOM use `window.onload` or jQuery's `$(document).ready()`

Also 'XHTML' and 'HTML' are not the same. XHTML is a very strict subset of HTML that in my opinion does nothing to improve upon regular HTML but it does allow for some fanciness. **It has no effect whatsoever on JavaScript.**

Answer (score 2):

Just put a script tag in the body of your page and it will run as the page is rendered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 // code goes here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged jQuery the way to do this is simply by including a [ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) function, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Assign your event handlers
});
```

Just put this code within a `<script type="text/javascript">` block within your page.